# Reconfigure Serilog Code Based Configuration at runtime that use values from appsettings

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, appsettings

I'd like to be able to setup most of my Serilog configuration via code configuration so that it can be more easily shared/maintained for multiple projects using our company's logging preferences (without having to duplicate/maintain multiple, complex appsettings.json files across multiple projects).

In my appsettings.json, I'd like to only manage logging levels and most importantly, I wanted to be able to simply enable and disable Serilog sinks at any point during runtime via configuration in appsettings.json.

I followed setup for my .NET Core project from [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#serilogaspnetcore---) and [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--).

My `Program.cs` looks like this (where I wrote the `RunWithSerilog` extension)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        CreateHostBuilder( args ).RunWithSerilog();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder( string[] args ) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults( webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            } );
}
```

I created the `RunWithSerilog` extension to enable multiple projects to reference the this library that configures Serilog correctly.

```
public static void RunWithSerilog( this IHostBuilder hostBuilder )
{
    // Generic logger to log bootstrap errors, real logger assigned after setup
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Override( "Microsoft", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information )
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        // Get setting objects I need to read during configuration
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath( System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() )
            .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json" )
            .AddJsonFile( $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" ) ?? "Production"}.json", true )
            .UseCamelotSecrets()
            .Build();

        var siteSettings = new SiteSettings();
        configuration
            .GetSection( TheKeep.SectionName )
            .GetSection( TheKeep.SiteSettingsSection )
            .Bind( siteSettings );

        var connectionStrings = new ConnectionStrings();
        configuration
            .GetSection( TheKeep.SectionName )
            .GetSection( TheKeep.ConnectionStringsSection )
            .Bind( connectionStrings );

        // https://github.com/Tolyandre/serilog-throw-context-enricher
        ThrowContextEnricher.EnsureInitialized();

        var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration( configuration )
            .Enrich.With<ThrowContextEnricher>()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.With<ActivityEnricher>()
            .Enrich.With<RemovePropertyEnricher>();

        if ( siteSettings.Logging.Sinks.File.Enabled )
        {
            var tempFilePath = "OmittedCode.json";

            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.File( new JsonFormatter(), tempFilePath, shared: true );
        }

        if ( siteSettings.Logging.Sinks.Seq.Enabled )
        {
            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Seq( connectionStrings.Seq );
        }

        if ( siteSettings.Logging.Sinks.Sql.Enabled )
        {
            var siteActivityColumnOptions = new ColumnOptions
            {
                // Omitted Code
            };

            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Conditional(
                $"SourceContext = '{typeof( PageLoggingFilter ).FullName}' and @l = 'Information'",
                config => config.MSSqlServer(
                    connectionStrings.Logging,
                    new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                    {
                        TableName = "SiteActivity",
                        AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
                        BatchPostingLimit = 50, // Default 50/5 results in 14K rows/sec, a test of 1000/5 resulted in 43K rows/sec
                        BatchPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 )
                    },
                    null,
                    null,
                    Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information,
                    null,
                    siteActivityColumnOptions
                )
            );
        }

        if ( siteSettings.Alerting.Telegram.Enabled )
        {
            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Conditional(
                    "@l = 'Error'",
                    config =>
                        config.Telegram(
                            "OmittedCode", // api id
                            "OmittedCode",
                            logEvent =>
                            {
                                var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                                sb.AppendLine( $"\U0001f621 {logEvent.RenderMessage()}" );
                                return new TelegramMessage( sb.ToString() );
                            }
                        )
                );
        }

        Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();

        Log.Information( "{ClientId}: Starting web host", siteSettings.ClientId );
        hostBuilder.Build().Run();
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        Log.Fatal( ex, "An unhandled exception occured during bootstrapping" );
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

During this setup, you can see I use values from appsettings in following locations

- `.ReadFrom.Configuration( configuration )`
- `if ( siteSettings.Logging.Sinks.File.Enabled )`
- `if ( siteSettings.Logging.Sinks.Seq.Enabled )`
- `loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Seq( connectionStrings.Seq );`
- `if ( siteSettings.Logging.Sinks.Sql.Enabled )`
- `connectionStrings.Logging,`
- `if ( siteSettings.Alerting.Telegram.Enabled )`
- `siteSettings.ClientId`

I'd like to be able to modify values in appsettings.json at runtime and have them be reflected immediately in my Serilog configuration.  Is this possible?

Note, I tried to use IOptionsSnapshot for settings and it didn't work either...something similar to the following (but I was also hesitant to be creating my own scopes):

```
public static void RunWithSerilog( this IHost host )
{
    SiteSettings siteSettings;

    using ( var scope = host.Services.CreateScope() )
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        siteSettings = services.GetService<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings>>().Value;
        var connectionStrings = services.GetService<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot<ConnectionStrings>>().Value;
        var configuration = services.GetService<IConfiguration>();

        // Omitted, same code from above starting with:
        // ThrowContextEnricher.EnsureInitialized();
        // through:
        // Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();
    }

    try
    {
        Log.Information( "{ClientId}: Starting web host", siteSettings.ClientId );
        host.Run();
    }
    catch ( Exception runEx )
    {
        Log.Fatal( runEx, "Host terminated unexpectedly" );
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

Comment: To override the configuration value, you could try to use [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-options-with-a-delegate) or [`System.IO.File` method](https://forums.asp.net/t/2148624.aspx?can+we+update+appsettings+json+in+controller+). If you want the updated value reflected immediately in your Serilog configuration, you should change the configuration value before configuring the Serilog.

Comment: Not sure I'm following your suggestion.  Could you write an answer with a little bit of pseudo code? As for 'you should change the configuration value before configuring the Serilog'...that's opposite of what I want, right?  Envision that the application is running, and I want to change the trace levels, or enable file trace for convenience, to debug an issue without having to restart the web application.